# Disable automatic "remind me on a day" in Reminders?

Tags: terminal, reminders

I use Reminders simply as a set of todo lists.

Today I created a reminder to "buy a shirt, size 14-1/2 32/33", and Reminders added a due date of "2016-01-14 12:00" (not sure how it calculated that exactly).

This addition of unwanted reminder dates commonly happens with other inputs, too (though I don't have another example before me at present).

Is there an app pref I could set through Terminal to disable this feature?

Mac OS X El Capitan (10.11.4)

Comment: By the way, I saw this—http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/134783/prevent-osx-from-auto-detecting-and-deleting-dates-in-ical-reminders—and thus tried `defaults write com.apple.mail DisableDataDetectors YES`, as well as `defaults write com.apple.reminders DisableDataDetectors YES`, to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

`14-1/2`is interpreted as a date, and tries to help you out. (2016-01-14)
There's no way to change this behavior in Reminders.app.

Comment: Can you supply a reference?

Answer (score 0):

Add a date and time after the sizes, and it create the reminder with only the last date as Reminder date, keeping the rest of the text without change.